# Question about the heatsink of my NVMe SSD

Tags: ssd, heat-sink

I've recently bought an NVMe SSD. The model is called "WD_BLACK SN850X NVMe SSD" (4 TB) and comes without a heatsink (according to the homepage of Western Digital). However, there's some sort of a black (and very flat) "pad" attached on top of the SSD, and I'm asking myself if that's a heatsink.

Pictures can be seen here:

https://www.westerndigital.com/products/internal-drives/wd-black-sn850x-nvme-ssd#WDS400T2X0E

On other NVMe SSDs one can see the different components, such as the controller, but this model has that flat pad attached to it.

Does anyone know if this is a heatsink, and whether I can/should add (another) one?

Comment: This is a Technical support request — Questions asking about troubleshooting hardware or technical support for hardware are off-topic for Hardware Recommendations because the site is here to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task, rather than to support existing devices. You may get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: According to the [datasheet](https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/product/internal-drives/wd-black-ssd/data-sheet-wd-black-sn850x-nvme-ssd.pdf) the 4TB version does not have a headsink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is without a heat sink.  The picture may be a generic one for all models.

It says it's `Part#: WDS400T2X0E`

Further down it says

> Product Numbers
> 1TB , Without Heatsink
> WDS100T2X0E
> 1TB , With Heatsink
> WDS100T2XHE
> 2TB , Without Heatsink
> WDS200T2X0E
> 2TB , With Heatsink
> WDS200T2XHE
> 4TB , Without Heatsink
> WDS400T2X0E